# Setting the renderer/editor of type Combobox in JTable

Tags: jtable, tablecellrenderer

I get a JTable which content is a Vector of class "item". The class item contains numeric and alphanumeric fields with proper getters/setters, except the field alt which is an ArrayList of strings. For this column I intended to use a comboBox-style renderer and editor in order to pick one of available choices and show the choice.
The alt field differs from row to row and that's what make me problem. I saw here a plenty of examples for such a renderer, but in all examples the available choices was the same for each row. Here's the code:

```
public class item extends Vector {

private int no, code;
private String ....;
private List<String> alt;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public item(int no, int code, ...., List alt) {
    super();
    this.add(no);
    this.add(code);
    .... 
    this.add(alt);
}

public int getNo() {
    return (int) this.get(0);
}

public void setNo(int no) {
    this.no = no;
}

// other setter/getters...

public void setAlt(List<String> alt) {
    this.alt = alt;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getAlt() {
    return (List<String>) this.get(6);
}

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public Vector getAsVector() {
    // ArrayList<Object> a= new ArrayList<Object>();
    Vector a = new Vector(7);
    a.add(no);
    a.add(sifra);
    a.add(red1);
    a.add(red2);
    a.add(sastojci);
    a.add(eanKod);
    a.add(alt);
    return a;
}
```

}

JTable get the necessary functions :

```
public Class getColumnClass(int ci){
    if (ci==6) return JComboBox.class;
    else return String.class;       
}


@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    item it = data.get(rowIndex);

    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        it.setNo((int) value);
        break;
    case 1:
        it.setCode((int) value);
        break;
    case 2:
        ....
    case 6:

        it.setAlt((List<String>) value);
        break;
    }
}   

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object returnValue = null;
    item it = data.get(rowIndex);

    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        returnValue = it.getNo();
        break;
    case 1:
        returnValue = it.getCode();
        break;
    case 2:
        ... 
    case 6:
        returnValue = it.getAlt();
        break;
    }

    return returnValue;
}       

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return columnIndex > 0;
}
```

And finally the renderer/editor classes:

```
    String[] sval = {"alfa", "Beta", "Gamma"};   //dummy array

protected class ComboRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    public ComboRenderer(){
        super(sval);            //works, but this is not I want
//      here should be used a similar super(list of options for a certain row), but how to get it?
//      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        setOpaque(true);
    }


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    if (isSelected) {
              setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
              setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
              setForeground(table.getForeground());
              setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }           
        this.setSelectedItem(items); 
        return this;
    }

}


protected class ComboEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
implements TableCellEditor {

    private List<String> alt;

    protected ComboEditor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return this.alt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof List) {
            this.alt = (List<String>) value;
        }

        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
    // combo.setEditable(true);   //does not work for editable combobox!
        for (String a : alt) {
            combo.addItem(a);
        }

        combo.setSelectedItem(alt);

        if (isSelected) {
          setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
          setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
          setForeground(table.getForeground());
          setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }           

        return combo;
    }

}
```

And here are the questions:

1) The renderer does not work obviously for wrong part of constructor (super(something)). But in this part I cannot obtain the rendered item, so i cannot obtain the list of choices for initialisation. How to solve that issue?

2) The editor seems to work well, but when I moved from the row it shows the old value again. Should I save here someting and how? There is no new data, just a choose between the options available for this item.

3) How to reach the chosen value for a certain row from outside, let's say for printing?

4) How will be possible to get an editable Combobox instead of fixed? The line

```
// combo.setEditable(true);   //does not work for editable combobox!
```

will not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

In meantime I solved the issues (except no. 4) but I think that must be a better solution, so I'm  still waiting the alternative solutions.

For first, I noticed that since I got one and only instance of renderer, the return value of

```
setSelectedItems(<available options>)
```

will return the selection in FIRST row for ALL other rows too, no matter what was selected there. So I decided to make one instance of renderer for every row. That means that the JTable constructor will contains the following code:

```
rendererList = new ArrayList<ComboRenderer>();
.... 
// create the Array of renderers, one for each row 
    for (int cnt=0; cnt<data.size(); cnt++){
        ComboRenderer a = new ComboRenderer(); 
        a.setOptions(cnt);
        rendererList.add(a);
    }
....
// telling to JTable which renderer to use for every cell    
@Override 
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int coll) {
    if (coll==6) return rendererList.get(row);
    else return this.getDefaultRenderer(this.getColumnClass(coll));     

}
```

The renderer and editor classes will look now as follows:

```
   protected class ComboRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    List<String> items;
    int selected;
    //selected will contains the index of selected option, changed through the cell editor as listener

    public ComboRenderer(){
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
        selected=0;   //initial value
    }

    public void setSel(int k) {
        selected=k;
    }

    public int getSel() {
        return selected;
    }
    // filling each renderer with available options; 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setOptions(int row) {
        items = data.get(row).getAlt();

        for (String a : items) {
            this.addItem(a);
        }
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (isSelected) {
              setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
              setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
              setForeground(table.getForeground());
              setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }    
        this.setSelectedIndex(selected);
        return this;
    }

}


class ComboEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

    private List<String> alt ;


    protected ComboEditor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return this.alt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof List) {
            this.alt = (List<String>) value;
        }

        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
        for (String a : alt) {
            combo.addItem(a);
        }
        final ComboRenderer  rend= rendererList.get(row);
        // adding actionlistener to letting know the renderer the selection 
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
               int i=((JComboBox<?>) arg0.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
               // telling the renderer the selection    
               rend.setSel(i);
            }
        });

        combo.setSelectedIndex(rend.getSel());

        if (isSelected) {
          setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
          setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
          setForeground(table.getForeground());
          setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }           

        return combo;
    }
}
```

It is working now, but the code looks for me very clumsy. There must be way to solve this issue on more elegant way. I simply can't believe that for each row must I have a distinct renderer, this is a waste of memory. Have anybody any idea?